# Bootstrap screen size dropdown menu transform translate

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a down like bootstrap dropdown, but I want to make the div position dynamic, how can I do it according to the screen size?

When IAMBUTTON is clicked, jquery automatically writes the "transform: translate" I have specified below. Likewise, when I click on the "New dropdown" button that I want to do, I want transform: translate to be added.

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-12 mb-1 mb-sm-0">
  <button class="btn btn-icon btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1001" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    IAMBUTTON
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1001">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-item" v-on:click="openMenu">
      <a class="test dropstart" tabindex="-1" data-popper-placement="left-start">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropstart" data-popper-placement="left-start" style="transform: scale(1);">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
    position: absolute;
    inset: auto auto 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    transform: translate(1071px, -407px);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code to us. Here is a link how to ask a well received question, you should check it out for the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have completely updated the topic, can you check?